Return NULL for CTE where records not found
I have this SQL query using a Common Table Expression:
with a as (
    select top 1 flow_id
    from flow
    where invoice_id > 0
), b as (
    select '45' as col2
)
select *
from a, b

if none of the rows satisfy the condition invoice_id>0 in the flow table, then I get the following result:

I want the following result even if no records are found from flow table:

Can this be done?

As per the question guide, please do not use images for data... use table markdown.

Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Can this be done? Answer is YES. By the way : Bad Habits to Kick: Old-style JOINs

select top 1 flow_id from flow where invoice_id > 0 will give you an arbitrary matching row in the event there is more than one. Do you need an ORDER BY here?

Does select MAX(flow_id) AS flow_id, 45  as col2 from flow where invoice_id > 0 do what you need?

You can do this:
with a as (
    select top 1 flow_id
    from (values(1,-1)) as flow (flow_id,invoice_id)
    where invoice_id > 0
), b as (
    select '45' as col2
)
select *
from a
right join b on 1 = 1

So, use a right join making sure any row on the right side table is in irrespective of whether a row on the left side is found based on the join condition. In this case, there is no real linking as you did a CROSS JOIN effectively, so the condition is 1=1 to reflect that.

I'm not a fan of artificial joins with 1 = 1. Outer apply allows us to avoid that e.g.
with a as (
    select top 1 flow_id
    from (values(1,-1)) as flow (flow_id,invoice_id)
    where invoice_id > 0
), b as (
    select '45' as col2
)
select a.*, b.*
from b
outer apply a;

Returns:



flow_id
col2




NULL
45




Yes it is completely possible.
A left join on a dummy column can help you with that .
with a as (
    select top 1 flow_id
    from flow
    where invoice_id > 0
), b as (
    select '45' as col2
)
select a.flow_id, b.col2
from b
left join a on 1 = 1

